# Is it possible to disable the scroll button (wheel) on a mouse?

Tags: mouse-wheel, dvr

Please READ before you answer.

I know this can be done with any operating system.

My issue is using a mouse with a stand alone DVR (Digital Video Recorder) that doesn't have a menu option to disable the scroll button. And i've searched for close to 2 hours and can't find any mouse that doesn't have a scroll button. I've called the DVR manufacturer and they said it's not possible to disable the scroll button functionality.

Suggestions or is my only option to open the mouse up and take out the wheel physically and hope it doesn't damage the mouse?

Edit: Mouse has to have 2 buttons: Left and right click capabilities at a minimum

Comment: Not the best looking mouse around, but [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Chester-Creek-CTMO-ChesterMouseTM-One-Button/dp/B006276108/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=mouse+no+scroll+wheel&qid=1555046663&s=gateway&sr=8-3) doesn't have a scroll wheel.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. It has to have 2 buttons. A Left click and right click.

Comment: Well, [here's](https://furniture-4kids.com/kitwobumowis.html) a two button version of that same brand of mouse, but the website kind of looks like it's stuck in 1997 so not sure I would go with that one.

Comment: I mean technically it would work. But I don't think my client is going to be pleased with his oversized man hands.

Comment: Gotcha. Who would have thought that finding a mouse without a scrollwheel would be so hard? You might have to just look for a used one on ebay or something. [Here's](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-USB-Optical-3-Button-Mouse-No-scroll-wheel-DY651A-/182294869080) my last suggestion and then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Hello, Just take out the scroll "button". :)